# Oauth_Signature / oauth_signature_method as headers restsharp

Tags: c#, http-headers, restsharp

I have an application I am writing to connect to a 3rd party company to receive data from their API. The code works fine below as it is, however they are instructing that my signatures need to be made as headers:

> Please provide the oauth signatures as headers instead of query parameters.

This works fine as it is without issue and can pull data successfully:

```
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("oauth_version", "1.0");
        request.AddParameter("oauth_nonce", GenerateNonce());
        request.AddParameter("oauth_timestamp", GenerateTimeStamp());
        request.AddParameter("oauth_signature_method", OAuthSignatureMethod.PlainText);
        request.AddParameter("oauth_consumer_key", _consumerKey);
        request.AddParameter("oauth_signature", GenerateSignature());
        request.Parameters.Sort(new QueryParameterComparer());
```

but when I try to make them as headers or inserting the ParameterType.HTTPHeader to the addparameter for the signatures, it gives me a 401 error.

Sorry if this is super simple, been searching google for the last 2 hours and read all the documents on RestSharp that I could find, but nothing seemed to be on what I needed.

Comment: That's how the OAuth1.0 doesn't work. You need to generate one single Header value which included all the parameters and add that value as "Authorization" header in the request. Check this http://docs.akana.com/cm/api_oauth/aaref/Ref_OAuth_AuthorizationHeader_10a.htm

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thank you! I haven't tried it yet, but that is exactly what I trying to find.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya would you have any idea how i would format in restsharp? I understand my mistake now, but not sure how the authorization header would be formatted :/

Comment: Did you try `request.AddHeader("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"consumerkey\", oauth_token=\"token\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_signature=\"signature\", oauth_timestamp=\"timestamp\", oauth_nonce=\"nonce\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"")`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I did :(